Can I use any linearly independent, orthogonal, eigenkets as starting basis to construct $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$?
I know how to construct $S_z$ using $|\uparrow\rangle$=$\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $|\downarrow\rangle$=$\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$ as starting basis. And I can also construct $S_x$, $S_y$ and derive our standard Pauli matrices.
With this any state can be generalized as $\chi$ = $a\cdot\chi_+ + b\cdot\chi_-$. But I'm not satisfied with the $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ as basis. I want to use different linearly independent vectors.
My questions are as follows

Are these the only available eigenkets? How about $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$

Why can't I use $|\uparrow\rangle = \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ and $|\downarrow\rangle = \left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ as my starting basis to construct $S_z$?


They satisfy all the requirements namely- orthogonality, linear independence, eigenvalue equation.

But if I use these new kets as basis then the matrix $$A = \sum_{a'} a' |a'\rangle \langle a'|$$ is no longer diagonal. But one of the requirements is that matrix $Sz$ must be diagonal if I use eigenkets as basis?

What am I missing?
Edit: I'm told in the comments that diagonal matrix must have $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$ as eigenstates. I can see why is that. I got that part- kind of. I would expect it to be diagonal because I used eigenkets as basis as told by Sakurai textbook.
But my other part of question is can I use $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ as starting basis?

??  This is very unclear.  If you have a diagonal matrix your eigenstates will be, up to an immaterial overall phase and normalization: $(1,0)^\top$ and $(0,1)^\top$.  The eigenstates you propose are just not eigenstates of a diagonal matrix (except a multiple of the unit matrix).

Ohh, I think I'm getting it now. You are right that diagonal matrix with different eigen values have $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ as eigenstates. But my other part of question is can I use $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ as basis? If I use them I will end up with totally different matrices!

yes but you’re putting the cart before the horse.  Start with operators and then get eigenstates, not the other way around.

@ZeroTheHero but all the books I have read first start with $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ to find operator $Sz$, not the other way around. And I want to use $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1,1)^T$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1,-1)^T$ as starting basis and get diagonal matrix for $S_z$ because Sakurai text book says we should get diagonal matrix if we use eigenkets as basis.

If you start with the eigenstates as above, you will trivially get a diagonal matrix.  If you start with some linear combination the resulting matrix will not be diagonal. There’s no two ways of splitting these statements: they just go together.

The eigenwhats, and eigenvalues of eigenvectors.

Of course, you can write the spin operators in the basis you prefer.
If you choose to work in the basis of the eigenstates of $S_z$ $\{|\uparrow\rangle,|\downarrow\rangle\}$, you get $S_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_x$, $S_y = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_y$ and $S_z = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_z$, where $\sigma_{x,y,z}$ are Pauli matrices, as you said.
But you can also choose to work in the basis of the eigenstates of $S_x$, $\{|\rightarrow\rangle, |\leftarrow\rangle\}$. In this case, you have that $S_x = \frac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_z$ is diagonal, whereas $S_y = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_y$ and $S_z = - \frac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_x$ are off-diagonal.
Notice that the new basis $\{|\rightarrow\rangle, |\leftarrow\rangle\}$ written in terms of the previous basis $\{|\uparrow\rangle, |\downarrow\rangle\}$ is
$$
|\leftarrow\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |\uparrow \rangle - |\downarrow\rangle \right)
$$
$$
|\rightarrow\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( |\uparrow \rangle + |\downarrow\rangle \right),
$$
which is the example you have mentioned.
Hope this helps!

No I don't want to write in basis of $S_x$. I want to write in basis of $S_z$ only. My question is can I use these vectors $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}\end{matrix}\right)$ as basis for Sz. What's special about $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$.

Wait, let's clarify the notation here. What is the physical meaning of the vectors $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ that you have chosen as canonical basis? Are they the eigenstates of $S_z$? Are they the eigenvalues of $S_x$? This is an arbitrary choice. In other words, if your system is in the state $(1,0)^T$, in what direction is your spin pointing?

I have chosen (1, 1/sqrt2) and (1, -1/sqrt2) as basis in z representation itself. Since they are orthogonal, linearly independent I can use them right? And now I want to construct Sz matrix using these as basis. And I want to get Sz as diagonal because  Sakurai textbook says I should get a matrix as diagonal when I write it in its eigenkets as basis.

@Siddaram, Perhaps You should include the exact quote in the question - since I think you might be misunderstanding it. Changing the basis of the eigenstates will correspondingly change the structure of the matrix representation of your observable. You can't require an observable to have a diagonal form in every basis - except for the case when its a multiple of the identity matrix.

I think the confusion partially comes from the use of row- and column-vector "tuple" notation when talking about a basis.
Think about the ordinary 2D Cartesian coordinate system that we learn about in middle school. What does a vector $v = \displaystyle \binom{2}{3}$ represent? Most people would answer "two right and three up" or something like that, but that depends on an assumption:
When we write $v = \displaystyle \binom{2}{3}$ we actually use a shorthand for
$$ v = 2 \vec{e_1} + 3 \vec{e_2}
$$
where our basis vectors are $\vec{e_1}$ and $\vec{e_2}$. In the 2D Cartesian coordinate system we almost unanimously mean $\vec{e_1}$ to be a unit vector pointing along the positive horizontal direction and $\vec{e_2}$ is the corresponding for the vertical direction.
For a spin 1/2 system, this choice of basis vectors is not so unanimous. In particular you mention using both the $z$ and $x$ directions to form your basis from. So, when you write $\displaystyle \binom{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}{\frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt 2}}$ it still seems like you mean
$$ \vec{w_\pm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |\uparrow_z \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} |\downarrow_z \rangle
$$
where I've used the more common braket notation for basis vectors in the QM context. I would argue that this is still in the $z$ basis! If you want to truly use $\vec{w_\pm}$ as a basis, i.e. have
$$ \vec{w_+} = \binom{1}{0}, \quad \vec{w_-} = \binom{0}{1}
$$
then you need to use a change-of-basis transformation (using a matrix) to change all vectors and matrices from the $z$ basis into this new basis. And as several people have already pointed out, $S_z$ will not be diagonal when
$$ \vec{w_+} = \binom{1}{0}, \quad \vec{w_-} = \binom{0}{1}
$$
Hope this helps.

Elementary computation starting with
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} a& b \\ b^* &c\end{pmatrix}
$$
show that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a& b \\ b^* &c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b^*\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $(1,0)^\top$ is not an eigenstate of $M$ unless $b=0$, in which case $M$ is diagonal.  By the same computation, neither is $(0,1)^\top$.
Conversely, if
$$
M'=\begin{pmatrix}a&0 \\ 0 &c\end{pmatrix}
$$
then
$$
M'\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ax\\ cy\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $(x,y)^\top$ is never an eigenvector unless $a=c$, in which case $M'$ is proportional to the identity matrix.
Therefore, while there is nothing wrong in starting with vectors of the form $(x,y)^\top$, do NOT expect they are eigenstates of a diagonal matrix unless it is a multiple of the unit matrix.
There's nothing else so say other than, if you start with $(x,y)^\top$, your $S_z$ will not be diagonal.
